# How to import 50GB of XML data into MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a XML file (50GB, 900M lines approx.), in which I wish to gather some data. I have calculated that these 900M lines in the XML-file will result in about 8M rows that are to be stored in the database. How should my approach be?

First, I thought of using a PHP script. This script should go through the whole file with XMLReader, gather the data for one row in an array, insert the data from that array in the database, delete that array (and thereby release memory) and so on (new array with data, insert in database, delete array etc.)

I was then told that this is an OK idea - however pretty dumb. This would take AGES and I would have some limits. Instead, I should think about importing the XML file directly to MySQL and then remove the unwanted data afterwards with SQL scripting. Is this the optimal approach? If so, could anyone elaborate on how this should be done?

Or is there an other/better approach?

**EDIT (Sample from the XML file):**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:ESStatistikListeModtag_I xmlns:ns="">
  <ns:StatistikSamling>
    <ns:Statistik>
      <ns:KoeretoejIdent>1026503230510888</ns:KoeretoejIdent>
      <ns:KoeretoejArtNummer>3</ns:KoeretoejArtNummer>
      <ns:KoeretoejArtNavn>Varebil</ns:KoeretoejArtNavn>
      <ns:KoeretoejAnvendelseStruktur>
        <ns:KoeretoejAnvendelseNummer>40</ns:KoeretoejAnvendelseNummer>
        <ns:KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn>Godstransport erhverv</ns:KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn>
      </ns:KoeretoejAnvendelseStruktur>
      <ns:RegistreringNummerNummer>TX90281</ns:RegistreringNummerNummer>
      <ns:RegistreringNummerUdloebDato>2010-11-19+01:00</ns:RegistreringNummerUdloebDato>
      <ns:KoeretoejOplysningGrundStruktur>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningOprettetUdFra>Typeattest</ns:KoeretoejOplysningOprettetUdFra>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningStatus>Eksporteret</ns:KoeretoejOplysningStatus>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningStatusDato>2011-04-06T00:00:00.000+02:00</ns:KoeretoejOplysningStatusDato>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato>2005-11-04+01:00</ns:KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer>JTDKC283800028896</ns:KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningTotalVaegt>1525</ns:KoeretoejOplysningTotalVaegt>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningEgenVaegt>1025</ns:KoeretoejOplysningEgenVaegt>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningTekniskTotalVaegt>1525</ns:KoeretoejOplysningTekniskTotalVaegt>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningAkselAntal>2</ns:KoeretoejOplysningAkselAntal>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningStoersteAkselTryk>825</ns:KoeretoejOplysningStoersteAkselTryk>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningTilkoblingMulighed>false</ns:KoeretoejOplysningTilkoblingMulighed>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningBlokering>false</ns:KoeretoejOplysningBlokering>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningTypeAnmeldelseNummer>A10253</ns:KoeretoejOplysningTypeAnmeldelseNummer>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningKommentar>DMR Konvertering</ns:KoeretoejOplysningKommentar>
        <ns:KoeretoejOplysningAntalGear>5</ns:KoeretoejOplysningAntalGear>
        <ns:KoeretoejBetegnelseStruktur>
          <ns:KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNummer>10265</ns:KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNummer>
          <ns:KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn>TOYOTA</ns:KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn>
          <ns:Model>
            <ns:KoeretoejModelTypeNummer>10265030</ns:KoeretoejModelTypeNummer>
            <ns:KoeretoejModelTypeNavn>YARIS</ns:KoeretoejModelTypeNavn>
          </ns:Model>
          <ns:Variant>
            <ns:KoeretoejVariantTypeNummer>1026503013</ns:KoeretoejVariantTypeNummer>
            <ns:KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn>1,4 VERSO TD</ns:KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn>
          </ns:Variant>
          <ns:Type>
            <ns:KoeretoejTypeTypeNummer>10265030130000001</ns:KoeretoejTypeTypeNummer>
            <ns:KoeretoejTypeTypeNavn>UOPLYST</ns:KoeretoejTypeTypeNavn>
          </ns:Type>
        </ns:KoeretoejBetegnelseStruktur>
        <ns:KoeretoejFarveStruktur>
          <ns:FarveTypeStruktur>
            <ns:FarveTypeNummer>1</ns:FarveTypeNummer>
            <ns:FarveTypeNavn>Ukendt</ns:FarveTypeNavn>
          </ns:FarveTypeStruktur>
        </ns:KoeretoejFarveStruktur>
        <ns:KarrosseriTypeStruktur/>
        <ns:KoeretoejSupplerendeKarrosseriSamlingStruktur>
          <ns:KoeretoejSupplerendeKarrosseriSamling>
            <ns:KoeretoejSupplerendeKarrosseriTypeStruktur>
              <ns:SupplerendeKarrosseriTypeNummer>61</ns:SupplerendeKarrosseriTypeNummer>
              <ns:SupplerendeKarrosseriTypeNavn>Lukket kasse</ns:SupplerendeKarrosseriTypeNavn>
            </ns:KoeretoejSupplerendeKarrosseriTypeStruktur>
          </ns:KoeretoejSupplerendeKarrosseriSamling>
        </ns:KoeretoejSupplerendeKarrosseriSamlingStruktur>
        <ns:KoeretoejNormStruktur>
          <ns:NormTypeStruktur>
            <ns:NormTypeNummer>24</ns:NormTypeNummer>
            <ns:NormTypeNavn>År 2000 miljønorm</ns:NormTypeNavn>
          </ns:NormTypeStruktur>
        </ns:KoeretoejNormStruktur>
        <ns:KoeretoejMiljoeOplysningStruktur>
          <ns:KoeretoejMiljoeOplysningPartikelFilter>false</ns:KoeretoejMiljoeOplysningPartikelFilter>
        </ns:KoeretoejMiljoeOplysningStruktur>
        <ns:KoeretoejMotorStruktur>
          <ns:KoeretoejMotorCylinderAntal>4</ns:KoeretoejMotorCylinderAntal>
          <ns:KoeretoejMotorSlagVolumen>1364.0</ns:KoeretoejMotorSlagVolumen>
          <ns:KoeretoejMotorStoersteEffekt>102.0</ns:KoeretoejMotorStoersteEffekt>
          <ns:DrivkraftTypeStruktur>
            <ns:DrivkraftTypeNummer>2</ns:DrivkraftTypeNummer>
            <ns:DrivkraftTypeNavn>Diesel</ns:DrivkraftTypeNavn>
          </ns:DrivkraftTypeStruktur>
        </ns:KoeretoejMotorStruktur>
      </ns:KoeretoejOplysningGrundStruktur>
      <ns:EjerBrugerSamling>
        <ns:EjerBruger>
          <ns:EjerBrugerForholdGrundStruktur>
            <ns:EjerBrugerForholdForhold>Bruger</ns:EjerBrugerForholdForhold>
            <ns:EjerBrugerForholdPrimaer>false</ns:EjerBrugerForholdPrimaer>
          </ns:EjerBrugerForholdGrundStruktur>
          <ns:PersonKoen>3</ns:PersonKoen>
        </ns:EjerBruger>
        <ns:EjerBruger>
          <ns:EjerBrugerForholdGrundStruktur>
            <ns:EjerBrugerForholdForhold>Ejer</ns:EjerBrugerForholdForhold>
            <ns:EjerBrugerForholdPrimaer>false</ns:EjerBrugerForholdPrimaer>
          </ns:EjerBrugerForholdGrundStruktur>
          <ns:PersonKoen>3</ns:PersonKoen>
        </ns:EjerBruger>
      </ns:EjerBrugerSamling>
      <ns:SynResultatStruktur>
        <ns:SynResultatSynsType>RegistreringsSyn</ns:SynResultatSynsType>
        <ns:SynResultatSynsDato>2011-02-25+01:00</ns:SynResultatSynsDato>
        <ns:SynResultatSynsResultat>Godkendt</ns:SynResultatSynsResultat>
        <ns:SynResultatSynStatus>Aktiv</ns:SynResultatSynStatus>
        <ns:SynResultatSynStatusDato>2011-02-25+01:00</ns:SynResultatSynStatusDato>
      </ns:SynResultatStruktur>
      <ns:KoeretoejRegistreringStatus>Afmeldt</ns:KoeretoejRegistreringStatus>
      <ns:KoeretoejRegistreringStatusDato>2010-11-19T00:00:00.000+01:00</ns:KoeretoejRegistreringStatusDato>
    </ns:Statistik>
  </ns:StatistikSamling>
</ns:ESStatistikListeModtag_I>
```

**ns:Statistik** contains data for one row. ns:Statistik should appear 6-8 mio times in the document.

Comment: I'm assuming that by 900 mio you mean 900 million (900,000,000). Could you share some sample data here? I think I might benchmark several approaches with a test data set to get a handle on relative efficiencies.

Comment: Is the xml formatted for a direct sql import? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html if not your need to do it manually, either way it will take a while.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm sure you meant programmatically rather than manually.

Comment: You should obviously, and absolutely be storing your data directly in the MySQL database, if you want to access it in any structured way.

Comment: @BigScar Yes, sorry for the shortcut. By 900 mio I mean 900,000,000 lines. See the edit. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Why wouldn't I be able to access it in a structured way by programmatically inserting the data in the database? I will not be needing all of the data. It's approx. only the half of the data (provided for one row) that I will be needing. So I would think that it was easier doing the other way, but it probably demands a lot of hardware power (CPU, RAM, etc..)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think you're missing the point.  The OP does want to store the data in the database - and he's asking for help on how to to import the data.  Also, don't make assumptions about others' data.  How do you imagine transferring the data over the network?  Or do you send over a mysql dump?

Comment: I think the question is evolving to "Should I preprocess the data and maybe cut the size in half before I hit the DB with it or after I hit the DB."

Comment: The title to this question needs edited then. It's incredibly misleading, implying that the OP wants to store a 50GB XML *file* in the database.  How about *"How to import 50GB of XML data into MySQL database"*?

Comment: I don't see a question here.Questions like "Is this the optimal approach?" that you ask here, do not count, because it highly depends on how it works out for you. Check as well the help center. So better do it and make your experience. The more direct an export is and the more existing the tools are (e.g. you can just automate with some little command-line), the more often, the better. Take the existing wheels, don't invent new ones. And yes, manually traversing large files takes time, so is it. However it does not take ages. There is nothing wrong with patience and import jobs.

Comment: @hskrijelj Is it possible for you to compress the 50G XML file, keep it on disk and just add the path to the file in the database? Otherwise, you could take each `ns:Statistik` and store in a separate record with `compress` function

Comment: I expect the XML loader in MySQL that Lawrence points out will be the fastest approach. However, I'd still be minded to split the XML files up - 50G files are rather cumbersome to deal with! If you can make them 0.25 or 0.5G each, that's much easier to handle, however you import.